# Angularjs $broadcast - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null

Tags: angularjs

I have a service communicating with Firebase, and for the login part of it I'm getting this error after broadcast a success login event, so basically my service looks like this:

```
angular.module('TestFire').factory('fireService', function ($rootScope, firebasePath, firebasePathToUsers, firebasePathToNicks) {

var fireRef = new Firebase(firebasePath);

    var s = {};
    s.logged = false;

    s.auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(fireRef, function(error, user) {
        if (user) {
            s.logged = true;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('UserLogged', user);

        } else {
            // user is logged out
            console.log('User is not logged');

        }
   return s;
}
```

In my login controller I want to redirect to the main page when the event is fired:

```
angular.module('TestFire').controller('loginUserController', function($location, $scope, fireService){

    $scope.facebookLogin = function (){
         fireService.loginUserWithFacebook();
    };

    $scope.$on('UserLogged', function(event, user) {
        $location.url('/');
        if (!$scope.$$phase){
            $scope.$apply();

        }
    });
});
```

If I don't use `$apply` the `$location` won't redirect, and if I use it I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null angular.min.js:94
$get.e.$broadcast
```

Although I get redirected later on the page is not responding to further actions, I assume that is caused by the previous error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest trying to use `$apply` in the master listener:

```
s.auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(fireRef, function(error, user) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        // original code here
    });
});
```

And of course remove the `$scope` manual handling from your `$on("UserLogged")` handler.

Comment: Well I finally used angularFire authentication, as I'm prototyping an app and I'm out of time, but yea, I tested out what you suggested and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nikos.  This is a good answer, it solved my problem and safe me from a lot of head banging. But I am still wondering what is the reason that it works with $rootscope.

Comment: The `$rootScope` is not the point, the point is to use `$apply` whenever you handle an event triggered outside Angular. The `$rootScope` is used there because it is a service and this is the only scope available.